# Background image: Does not continue in white color

Tags: html, css, web

First off, my website is: http://www.volunteeringnews.com

On the website I want white to continue to the bottom of the website but he is now cutting it just after the background image.

I could offcourse make my img 10000 px high but that seems to create a very big image in size.

So far I tried creating a new Div to go around the background divs but then he just goes over the background divs.

I tried z-index but that did nothing.

I tried to use the IMG from HTML and not CSS but that got my img out of line. (I have the background split in two images for the top and the main section).

I've been on it all day and hoped that someone might be able to help me out.

ps.I'm sorry if this is kind of a noob question but I am only on building websites for a few months.

Thank you!

```
#head{
margin:0px;
height:215px;
background-image:url(../img/background/background_01.gif);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
width:100%;


}

#mainc {


margin-top: 0px;
width:90%;
position:absolute;
background-image:url(../img/background/background_02.gif);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
min-height:100%;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

```
background-color:#fff;
```

to your `#mainc` and `#head` as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

just by adding

```
background-color: #FFFFFF;
```

to your #mainc  style should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

First off start by cleaning up your html which currently looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Volunteering News- All your volunteering news plus a database to look for your own advernture. - Cheap and free</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="wordpress\wp-content\themes\twentytwelve\style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<meta name="Volunteering" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head>

<!--body-->

    <body>
<div class="topnav"></div>
<header><!doctype html>
<html lang="en">        
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Volunteering Field- Volunteer direct, cheap and easy</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

<meta name="Volunteering" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<div class ="sql">
</div>

</head>



<body>

<div id="wrapper">
             <img src="img/form/background.jpg" class="stretch" alt="" />
</div> 

    <div id="head">

        <div class="logo">
            <img src="img/head/logo.png">
        </div>




        <div class="menu-top">
            <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Volunteering Field- Volunteer direct, cheap and easy</title>
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

<meta name="Volunteering" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head> 

<body>
<div id="navigation">
<ul id="nav" class="drop">

  <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
```

You have multiple doctypes, multiple html tags, multiple head tags, multiple css declarations. This will never work properly.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I use php with: <div class="mainc1"><?php include("sideleft.php");?></div> for example. If I go to view source it seems like a big mess but in my editor it links to other php documents to creat order.. Is this what you mean or am I not understanding your comment?

Comment: Look at the generated source from your browser. Its super messed up, you need to fix this before anything else. Maybe the included phps have one too many doctype etc?

Comment: Allright, i'll have a look at it tomorrow, thanks for the heads up!!